# Service - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to put together a service for my controllers. But I keep getting an error saying 
"Cannot read property 'industriesArr' of undefined". I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding something fundamental, so please educate me.

Service:

```
angular.module('core').service('FormService', function() {
    var data = {
        'industriesArr': [
            'Alcoholic Drinks','Animals and Pets','Arts and Entertainment',
            'Baby and Toddler','Banking','Beauty and Personal Care','Building and Construction',
            'Clothing and Footwear','Communication Services','Confectionary and Snacks',
            'Dining and Nightlife',
            'Education and Jobs','Electronics and Technology',
            'Family and Community','Fast food and Restaurant','Financial Services','Food and Groceries',
            'Games and Toys','Government and Law',
            'Health','Home and Garden',
            'Insurances','Internet, Telecom and Software',
            'Jewelry and Luxury',
            'Leisure',
            'Media and Publications',
            'News','Non-alcoholic Drinks','Non-profit Organisation',
            'Occasions and Gifts','Office Supplies','Other',
            'Personal Accessories','Pharmaceutical and Medical','Political Organisation','Professional Services','Public Interest',
            'Real Estate','Retail Services and Wholesaler',
            'Sports Accessories','Sports and Fitness',
            'Tobacco','Tourism and Travel','Transport',
            'Utilities',
            'Vehicles'
        ]
    };
    return data;

});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('core').controller('SignupController', ['$scope', 'FormService', function($scope, FormService) {
    $scope.industriesArr = FormService.data.industriesArr;
});]);
```

HTML is simply:

```
<p ng-repeat="industry in industriesArr">{{industry}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are returning data you should use factory. So instead of this

`angular.module('core').service('FormService', function() {`

Use this

`angular.module('core').factory('FormService', function() {`

When the service syntax is used Angular treats it as Constructor function. If you want to use service do not do `return` and define your properties\functions on `this`  such as

`this.industriesArr=[...];`

Comment: Thanks for that. As per your suggestion, I'm using the service syntax with `this.industriesArr = ['ind1', 'ind2'];`. In the controller, I'm calling `console.log(FormService.industriesArr);`, however this is returning `undefined`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Nvm, I've ended up fixing my own silly error. However, thanks for letting me know about not using return with services!

Answer (score 0):

Write your module like this :

```
angular.module('core').service('FormService', function() {
    return{
        getData: function() {
           return { 'industriesArr': [...]; }
        }
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Made a silly mistake and put FormService in the incorrect order when associating it with my controller.